# cakephp associative table relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, relationship

I have 3 tables
students(id,name)
subjects(id, subject)
student_subjects(id,student_id,subject_id)

`students` table is related to `subjects` on `many to many` relation using `student_subjects` table

student model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'studentsSubject' => array(
        'className' => 'studentsSubject',
        'foreignKey' => 'students_id',
    ));
```

students_subjects model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'className' => 'Student',
        'foreignKey' => 'students_id',
    ));
```

when I query

```
$students = $this->Student->find('all');
debug($students);exit();
```

it returns like this

```
array(
 'Student' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'smith',
 ),
 'StudentSubject' => array(
     0=>array(
        'id' => '1',
        'student_id'=>'1',
        'subject_id'=>'1'
       ),
      1=>array(
        'id' => '2',
        'student_id'=>'1',
        'subject_id'=>'2'
       ),
   )
 )
```

while I want to have subject names instead of subjectID as below
I know I can make changes in `find` to have required result
but I mean, Is it possible like link `students` table with 'subjects' instead of 'student_subjects'

```
  array(
 'Student' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'smith',
 ),
 'Subject' => array(
     0=>array(
        'id' => '1',
        'subject'=>'maths',
       ),
      1=>array(
        'id' => '2',
        'subject'=>'computer',
       ),
   )
 )
```

Comment: Read about the [HABTM model association](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

Answer (score 2):

You made belongsTo with Student in students_subjects model. This is incorrect. Instead of that you need to make belongsTo with Subject.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you should use a [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) assosiation. With your three tables defined as you have, you need just two models and the HABTM relationship between them.

```
class Student extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Subject' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Subject',
            'joinTable' => 'student_subjects',
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

This way, you would have access as you want to the Subject model, through the Student model without any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Change model class name

```
Class Subject extends App_Model{

    public $useTable = 'student_subjects';

  }
```

Comment: This is not the _cake way_ to do it